# How to get element from nested JSON Array object with max value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I want Category 1 max value 157. I can achieve this by using for or forEach though. But can anyone guide me on how to achieve this by using ES6?

Also I want the full object so I can use other fields too. eg. expiry

```
{
                "data": [
                    {
                        "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "rates": [
                            {
                                "name": "Category 1",
                                "amount": 57
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Category 2",
                                "amount": 55
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "rates": [
                            {
                                "name": "Category 1",
                                "amount": 157
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Category 2",
                                "amount": 25
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
                        "rates": [
                            {
                                "name": "Category 1",
                                "amount": 27
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "Category 2",
                                "amount": 45
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "data": [{
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 57
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 55
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 157
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 25
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 27
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 45
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};

var arr = [];

for (var i of jsonObj.data) {
 arr.push(i.rates.find((obj) => obj.name === 'Category 1'));
}

var maxValue = Math.max.apply(Math, arr.map(function(obj) { return obj.amount; }));

console.log(maxValue); // 157
```

Comment: I can do the same using for loop but want to use es6 - es10. Thanks for reply.
I dont want to use for loop.

Answer (score 0):

**Try It**

```js
var jsonData= {
 "data": [{
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 57
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 55
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 157
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 25
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "expiry": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "rates": [{
     "name": "Category 1",
     "amount": 27
    },
    {
     "name": "Category 2",
     "amount": 45
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
};

var vAllAmountForCategory1=[];

for (i = 0; i < jsonData.data.length; i++) {
 var pData= jsonData.data[i];
 for (j = 0; j < jsonData.data[i].rates.length; j++) { 
   if(jsonData.data[i].rates[j].name=="Category 1"){
    vAllAmountForCategory1.push(jsonData.data[i].rates[j].amount);
    }
  }
}

var vValueAmountSortingInDesc=vAllAmountForCategory1.sort(function(a, b){return b - 
 a});

console.log("The max amount for 'Category 1' is:  "+vValueAmountSortingInDesc[0]);
```

**Or You can also use **[LinkJS](http://neue.cc/reference.htm)

Comment: I can do the same using for loop but want to use es6 - es10. Thanks for reply.
I dont want to use for loop.